# How to delete default lines behind tabbing inside itemize?

Tags: itemize

Can you help me, how to make contious text if using tabbing instide the itemize, please?

```
\item \textbf{Sirius}

\begin{nstabbing}

{\bfseries Rektascenze:} \= 06h 45m 08,9s\\

{\bfseries Deklinace:} \> −16° 42′ 58″\\

\end{nstabbing}

\noindent
Sirius je naopak nejjasnější hvězdou noční oblohy (−1,46 mag).
```

First figure is the Latex version

Second figure is the desired version in Word

[image: Tabbing inside Itemize Latex][image: Tabbing inside Itemize Word]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which can be compiled as it is and which reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set these distances using the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en) package.

If you don't want bullets or spaces, though I'm not sure itemize is the right environment to be using!

You didn't provide a full example, or how the `nstabbing` environment is defined, so here's something just using `tabbing`:

```
... (in header)
\usepackage{enumitem}
...
\begin{itemize}[label={},leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=0pt,nolistsep]
\item \textbf{Sirius}%
\vspace*{-2ex}
\begin{tabbing}
{\bfseries Rektascenze:} \= 06h 45m 08,9s\\
{\bfseries Deklinace:} \> −16° 42′ 58″\\
\end{tabbing}\vspace*{-4.5ex}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works for first blank line, but in the case of second, using \vspace*{-2ex} does not make any change... :/

Comment: You may need to play around with the exact amount but for me `\vspace*{-4.5ex}` put *between* the `\end{tabbing}` and `\end{itemize}` works. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thaks, now its better

Comment: Maybe accept my answer then, or at least upvote it?